# Why does my prism template give an Android.views.InflateException from the default template?

Tags: c#, windows, cross-platform, prism, visual-studio-2019

I recently downloaded the prism template pack for Xamarin from https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. After I start a new project and attempt to run it, I just get the error as shown in the image attached. I simply created the project and ran the application. No changes.Error description `Android.Views.InflateException
  Message=Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
.`. Both the Resource.Layout.Toolbar as well as tabbar have the error `Ambiguity between Resource.Layout.Toolbar and Resource.Layout.Toolbar`. Any help would seriously be appreciated. Please let me know if I can add anything else.[Screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kag5.png)

Comment: which version of Android is it targeting? Can you provide a link to a created project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem using Android 9 & 10. I've created a Prism demo out of the box here: github.com/wsigel/PrismError
For comparison I've created a blank xamarin.forms app and there is no problem with the Tabbbar/Toolbar in MainActivity.cs